# Preventing an application from accessing a database

Tags: oracle, exe

We have a terminal server that has two copies of our application: a live version, and a test version.

These are 2 icons on the users desktop. Now when you launch the application, you type in the name of the oracle database that the application connects to.

We want to prevent users accessing the production database when they use the TEST icon, and prevent users accessing the TEST environments when they use the PROD icon.

Unfortunately we can't do this through the application, and we do not want to go down the route of getting the application modified by the vendor. The application uses a single tnsnames.ora file to connect to the database for both the test version and the prod version, so we can't change this (unless there is a way to use multiples?).

I was thinking we could have a local firewall that would prevent the test application from accessing the live server (just block the connection), but at the moment, they are both on the same server!

So, can anyone think of a way to prevent a certain application accessing an Oracle database? The application EXE has the same name, but it is run from a different path depending if it is a test version or the prod version.

Comment: Can you prevent the user from typing in the name of the database? That is, hard-code the name of the database so that the test application automatically connect to the correct database.

Comment: Can you create `.bat` files that set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable and then launch the real applications; and the terminal server icons are changed to point to the batch file? Then each can have its own `tnsnames.ora` with a single entry? (I'm assuming the app doesn't take a command-line switch to set the Oracle alias automatically).

Comment: Nope can't hardcore anything- cant change the application. @Alex- Won't setting the tns_admin affect existing sessions on the server?

Comment: Not if you set it in a wrapper batch script around the application - it will only affect things launched within that `.bat`. And it doesn't affect the DB server at all, if that's what you mean; it's just a look-up to resolve the alias your user types in (similar to a `hosts` file, kinda).

Comment: Thanks Alex. That looked like it worked. You should put your comment as an answer and then I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control of the environment on the terminal server, one fairly simple option is to wrap the application in a batch file that forces it to use a restricted `tnsnames.ora`.

Create two directories, e.g. `test_tns_admin` and `live_tns_admin`. Put a copy of your `tnsnames.ora` in each directory, but edit them so each only has the TNS alias for one target database.

Create two batch files, e.g. `live.bat` and `test.bat`. In each, set the `TNS_ADMIN` admin variable to point to the appropriate directory, and then launch the real application. So `test.bat` might look like:

```
::Batch wrapper for the TEST application
@set TNS_ADMIN="\path\to\test_tns_admin"
@"\path\to\real\application.exe"
```

... and `live.bat` is the same but pointing to the other directory. You can put shortcuts to the batch files on the desktop instead of the real applications. When one of those is run and the the application launches, the `TNS_ADMIN` will mean it picks up the cut-down `tns_names.ora`, so only the `TEST` TNS alias will be recognised. Nothing else on the terminal server or database is affected.

You don't even really need two new `tnsnames.ora` files; you could remove the `TEST` alias from the existing system-wide one and leave the live application alone, only replacing the test launcher with a batch file - that might be preferable since live isn't touched, but depends how you want to manage it, and whether it will be clearer to have them both working the same way.

Comment: @M.Heydari - no, look at the comment history against the question itself; I suggested it and Lock tried it before you added the comment on your answer. We had the same idea but I didn't copy you or base my answer on your comment at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a view called v$session
and the query bellow shows any session information

```
select username,program
from   v$session
```

You may have a table for listing restricted(or allowed) program names

```
CREATE TABLE RESTRICTED_PROGRAMS(
PROGRAM_NAME     VARCHAR2(64))

INSERT INTO RESTRICTED_PROGRAMS VALUES ('TEST.exe');
COMMIT;
```

you can use the script bellow to create a ***AFTER LOGON ON TRIGGER***

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon_audit
  AFTER LOGON ON database
DECLARE
  v_program            VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT program into v_program;
      FROM v$session
     WHERE audsid = userenv('sessionid');


  for x in (SELECT * FROM RESTRICTED_PROGRAMS) loop
    IF upper(v_program) == upper(x.PROGRAM_NAME) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,
                              'You are not allowed to login using ' ||
                              v_program);
    end if;
  end loop;
END;
```

If a user can connect to you database using application X.exe, then if they rename Y.exe to X then they're still in.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but the application name is the same with live and prod. I can change the exe name, but the launcher launches a exe called menu.exe, so I can't change this between the two

Comment: There may be an insane way: you can have two versions of TNS.ora file in separate locations (one for Dev and one for Test), then you must write a batch file for each .Exe, in the Bach files first you will copy and replace  .Ora file, next you will call the .exe,  you have to replace shortcuts of these 2 new Bach files will old shortcuts on your desktop ...